# Cannot list items with *ngFor

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

i want to make a simple adding friend and friend requests page for my app. i am using angularjs , angularfire2 and ionic 3.

```
    <ion-list>

  <ion-item *ngFor="let friendrequest of friendRequestArray; let i = index">
    <h2>{{friendrequest.$value}}</h2>

    <button ion-button  item-end>Accept</button>
    <button ion-button  item-end>Decline</button>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

my ts code:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
public alertCtrl: AlertController, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

  this.myUid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

  this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.myUid}/friendrequests/`).subscribe(data => {

    this.friendRequestArray = data;
    console.log(this.friendRequestArray);
  });
```

}

i am getting a console output like this:

[so its working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdITZ.jpg)

error is:

```
   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

my data:

```
 "users" : {
"3YG0aYta1AP28COa7hdopwvICt63" : {
  "friendrequests" : {
    "test2" : "7LXXTyAH9MeKyqRBg3oP7b2Juox2",
    "test4" : "BaKWaeGrTzXHe4EQ60gpWYOoxKD2",
    "test6" : "nNl6pa0s7ZXULV0yFSIV4dLP0s13"
```

i couldnt understand what it says. what i am doing wrong ? i can subscribe data in array form like i want but cannot list it with *ngfor please assist me thanks.

Comment: `friendrequests` is not an Array. It is a object with key, value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you have structured your data from firebase but friend request is not an Array so Angular can't iterate over it.

You can fix this by re-structuring your data to:

```
"users" : {
"3YG0aYta1AP28COa7hdopwvICt63" : {
  "friendrequests" : [ 
   { "test1" : "7LXXTyAH9MeKyqRBg3oP7b2Juox2" },
   { "test2" : "7LXXTyAH9MeKyqRBg3oP7b2Juox2" },
]
```

Then you can do the loop from the template but don't forget to next the response value properly like this:

```
this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.myUid}/friendrequests/`).subscribe(data => {

    this.friendRequestArray = data.this.myuid.friendrequests;
    console.log(this.friendRequestArray);
  });
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i am basically using this code to create friendrequests;    **this.afDatabase.object(`users/${this.targetUid}/friendrequests/${this.myUsername}`).set(this.myUid);** so how can i re-structure that data to array ?

Comment: I am not a firebase expert but I am very sure this is possible. However, if you find a way to do this let me know but my answer contains how the data structure should look.  Thanks for accepting my answer.